# How to run a program without JIT?

Tags: c#, java, compiler-construction, runtime, jit

How can we run a Java or C# program without JIT help?

pseudocode:

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    // open file in append mode
    // remove last line
    // add a line
    // close the file
    // if any exception occurs, continue with next iteration
}
```

How to compare the performance of this program when JIT is enabled/disabled?

Comment: **Moderator note** *There was no way I could surgically remove comments that were more noise than signal without leaving a completely broken conversation in my wake. Subsequently, comments under this question have been purged. If you want to have a constructive conversation about this question, please use chat. If you have constructive and friendly questions or points, feel free to post them here. The key words are constructive and friendly.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to run .NET code without a JIT, even with Mono (its bytecode interpreter is not supported any more).

It is possible to turn the JIT off for many JVM implementations, e.g., `-Xint` for Sun JVM.

Answer (score 3):

In .Net you can run a program without jit only by pre compiling the intermediate language to the target machine specific code first.  [NGen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf.aspx) is a tool that does this for .net.

According to [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adioltean/archive/2005/03/25/402099.aspx) you can use GCJ to do something similar for java:

> GCJ (the GNU Java compiler) can compile .class files into executable objects which can then be linked into a .exe file, or even C++ files. Of course, the final exe / library will end up with GC & Java runtime (statically / dynamically linked .LIB) dependencies.

Comment: If i understand it correct, @Azodious wants to run the CIL in the .NET virtual machine (as opposed to compiling CIL to machine-specific code first and natively executing compiled code second). Your message is on the completely different matter: **when** there will be CIL to machine-specific code compilation (made in advance by NGen or on first run with JIT compiler).

Comment: @penartur on second reading maybe you are right...  In which case the answer for .net is that you can't :)

Comment: Isn't the jit deactivated/pretty limited if you start the code under the debugger? There's a pretty big difference between the produced code when starting it under the debugger, compared to attaching the debugger to the running process.

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle JVM accepts `-Djava.compiler=NONE` to disable the JIT (`-D` sets the system property, [`java.compiler` is the property name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29), `NONE` is the value). No idea about .Net (C#).

Answer (score 1):

When code is first run it is interpreted. Only after it has been run many times (typically 10,000) does it get compiled. For CPU intensive tasks this can make a big difference.  However, for IO intensive tasks, the OS and the hardware you have make much more difference.

So for a loop of only 100, you can be sure it won't be compiled to native code, whether you enable the compiler or not.  For an IO intensive task (and open/closing a file is very expensive) whether the code is compiled or not makes such a small difference you will have trouble measuring it.